# Resource interpreted as image but transfered with MIME type text/html

Tags: html

> resource interpreted as image but transfered with MIME type text/html: адрес главной страницы

На сайте появляется данная надпись, в хроме в средствах разработчика. Все перекопал. Никак не пойму, что не так указал. Понятно из текста, что тип страницы указан как картинка, но где копать, не пойму. И почему адрес главной страницы всегда. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Все хорошо. Не волнуйтесь :)

Comment: А я б перевел по-другому: Ресурс интерпретирован (распознан) как рисунок, но указанный MIME-тип - "text/html". Соответственно, можно предположить, что у Вас что-то не так в настройках mime-типов на сервере. В apache они прописываются в ..\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\mime.types

Answer (score 1):

Если php то попробуй отправить тип контента, возможно в настройках веб-сервера указана отправка типа контента как рисунок, но такое вряд ли.

```
header("Content-type: text/html;");
```